# Google Map v2 Fragment Error

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

i write simple google map v2 android application but in my java file
this line:

```
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

have error!
error:the getFragmentManager() is undefined for the type mainActivity.
please help me my friends.

Comment: What does your MainActivity extend?

Comment: FragmentActivity extend my friend

Comment: Use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`.

Comment: I think this [link](http://dhruvvaishnav.blogspot.in/2013/10/android-google-map-v2.html) helps you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you used `SupportMapFragment` then used `getSupportFragmentManager()`

and if you used `MapFragment` then used `getFragmentManager()`

### **Correct**

```
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Comment: change it and solve this line but when I run now crash!

Comment: @user3703052 post your logcat then.

Comment: Tag:AndroidRuntime and Text:at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java.290)

Comment: @user3703052 edit your question and post your all logcat there and also post the code where you got this crash.

Answer (score 0):

Try This code:

map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();